# Using ProcessBuilder to execute Linux Command and getting NULL from reader.readLine() although line count is 102

Tags: java, inputstream, bufferedreader, processbuilder

I get a NULL when trying to print the lines from the InputStream.
The line count does return a value and the file I am opening does contain the same amount of lines.

`reader.readLine()` returns NULL.

`reader.lines().count()` does return the correct amount of lines in the file...

So it leads me to believe that:

1. The command was executed successfully.
2. The file was opened and read successfully.
3. The correct Stream is being used. i.e. `process.getInputStream()`

I am trying to use Java to run a linux command that will open a file which is located on the server and print it out / log it to my log file.

I've tried using ProcessBuiler and `Runtime.getRuntime.exec()`. Both yield the same result... a NULL on `reader.readLine()`.

Some posts suggested using the `process.getOutputStream`. Which returned a 0 line count and null lines.

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
processBuilder.command("sh", "-c", "cat chris.txt");
processBuilder.directory(new File("/opt/tmp/FOLDER_NAME"));
Process process = processBuilder.start();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
stringBuilder.append(line);
logger.info("######### {}", line);
}
```

I am expecting to get the contents of my file printed in my log file.

I am getting a NULL on the `reader.readLine()` object.

Comment: Of course: `stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");` as `line` was stripped of any line separator char(s).

Comment: Yes. But first I need reader.readLine() not to return null.

Answer (score 1):

A `null` return value from `readLine()` means that you have reached the end of the stream. Thus your process does not produce any output.

In case the file actually has some content, the most likely reason for no output is that your sub-process failed. For example because it could not find the shell, could not find the file, the file was not accessible, ...

Check the return value of `process.waitFor()`. If this is anything else but 0 then there was a problem. You may also want to capture the `stderr` of your process since that contains potential error messages. An easy way to do that is to redirect the error stream to the output stream using `ProcessBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true)`.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that null should mean that I've reached the end of the stream, however, it makes no sense that I've reached the end of the stream.

The shell command is run and the file is found. I know this because reader.lines().count() comes back with the exact number of lines in my file.

I've redirected the error stream and nothing comes through as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue...
Seems that I was using up the stream by doing a line count prior to using the lines.

A comment on another post helped me find this...

"The while and the for both behave essentially the same way; the reason why your while never "returned" is probably due to your "exhausting" the stream in the countlines() method."

Comment: I don't see any line counting code in the code sample you posted? I just tried your code sample here and it works fine.